# UITableView does not responding to selection of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i have created a `UItableView` named **_tableView**, here is the code for table view in view.m

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
         [super viewDidLoad];

         tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Team Members",@"MembershipStatus",@"relation of status",@"Registerd events", nil];
                [_tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
                 [_tableView  reloadData];
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [tableData count];
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 54;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [newCell setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
        newCell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return  newCell;

    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSLog(@"id");
    }
```

while executing the code I got the table correctly. But when i am selecting one of the list item it won't respond. (i.e., the **NSLog** is not working). did i miss something ?? or what i do wrong ??

Comment: Did you set delegate of UITableView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `-viewDidLoad` write:

```
[_tableView setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the `tableview's` `delegate` is set to your viewController

```
@interface MyView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

in `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.tableview.delegate=self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with your code

```
@interface ClassName : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
in viewDidLoad:


self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

or

_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

check in .h file 
@interface MyView : UIViewController  is set or Not. if its not set then Set 1st there.
then in .m File while Creating TableView there
you just write

_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;